# How to pass data back to parent activity

Tags: java, android

On my app I see having multiple activities...

```
            Main
              |
     --------------------
   Login                 |
     |                   |
     --------------- Dashboard
                         |
     -----------------------------------------
     |                   |                   |
 Activity1           Activity2            Activity3
```

If a user is logged in, it will bypass login and head straight to dashboard.  Then I see the dashboard launching other activities.  Currently, my main activity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    User user = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

I've tried to find sample code showing how to pass data from my login activity back to Main, but I've been struggling.  I can find many examples of how to pass data from a parent activity to a child activity, but not the other way around.

PS - If I'm not on the right track with my app, please let me know!

Comment: +1 for taking the time to make your diagram!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into startActivityForResult?

Please see this tutorial:
http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/